# Grouping multiple days together

Tags: sql, sql-server

i have a query that gets data about employee clock times. this query also adds a field called inDay, groups the rows by day and gives them a number. so that i can datediff the rows to get the correct worked times.

```
    SELECT     CHINA_VISION_PubPersonnel.Name, CHINA_VISION_PubPersonnel.ID, CHINA_VISION_PubCards.CardCode, CHINA_VISION_PubPersonnel.Telephone, ATDShiftDetail.EndOverDay, 
                          CHINA_VISION_DorEvents.EventTM AS T, CONVERT(VARCHAR(10), CHINA_VISION_DorEvents.EventTM, 102) AS Day, FLOOR(CONVERT(FLOAT, 
                          CHINA_VISION_DorEvents.EventTM)) AS DayNumber,    
                          ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY FLOOR(CONVERT(FLOAT,CHINA_VISION_DorEvents.EventTm)) ORDER BY CHINA_VISION_DorEvents.EventTm) InDay  
    FROM         CHINA_VISION_PubCards INNER JOIN
                          CHINA_VISION_PubPersonnel ON CHINA_VISION_PubCards.PubPersonnel_Ref = CHINA_VISION_PubPersonnel.Reference INNER JOIN
                          CHINA_VISION_DorEvents ON CHINA_VISION_PubCards.CardCode = CHINA_VISION_DorEvents.CardCode INNER JOIN
                          ATDShiftDetail ON RIGHT(CHINA_VISION_PubPersonnel.ID, 4) = ATDShiftDetail.Name
    WHERE     (CHINA_VISION_DorEvents.DorCtrls_Ref = '16') AND (CHINA_VISION_DorEvents.CardCode = '0042f55c') AND (CONVERT(Date, CHINA_VISION_DorEvents.EventTM) 
                          > DATEADD(day, - 6, GETDATE())) AND ATDShiftDetail.EndOverDay = '1'
```

example output data.

```
        Name    ID  CardCode Telephone  EndOverDay          T                   Day   DayNumber InDay
        ----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    Joe Blogs   1   0042f55c    8           1       2015-11-06 01:17:05.000 2015.11.06  42312   1
    Joe Blogs   1   0042f55c    8           1       2015-11-06 01:45:44.000 2015.11.06  42312   2
    Joe Blogs   1   0042f55c    8           1       2015-11-06 07:45:56.000 2015.11.06  42312   3
    Joe Blogs   1   0042f55c    8           1       2015-11-09 19:39:21.000 2015.11.09  42315   1
    Joe Blogs   1   0042f55c    8           1       2015-11-10 01:11:15.000 2015.11.10  42316   1
    Joe Blogs   1   0042f55c    8           1       2015-11-10 01:36:39.000 2015.11.10  42316   2
    Joe Blogs   1   0042f55c    8           1       2015-11-10 07:57:02.000 2015.11.10  42316   3
    Joe Blogs   1   0042f55c    8           1       2015-11-10 19:42:45.000 2015.11.10  42316   4
    Joe Blogs   1   0042f55c    8           1       2015-11-11 01:16:07.000 2015.11.11  42317   1
    Joe Blogs   1   0042f55c    8           1       2015-11-11 01:40:06.000 2015.11.11  42317   2
    Joe Blogs   1   0042f55c    8           1       2015-11-11 07:55:20.000 2015.11.11  42317   3
```

However this employee works nights, that means i need to group the last record from the night before, which will be when they clock on with the next three records.

using the output above here is what the out put should be like.

once the data is how i like i can then Datediff the rows to get the employee work hours.

```
        Name    ID  CardCode Telephone  EndOverDay          T                   Day   DayNumber InDay
        ----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    Joe Blogs   1   0042f55c    8           1       2015-11-06 01:17:05.000 2015.11.06  42312   1 -- were missing the record from the night before so start at 1 here
    Joe Blogs   1   0042f55c    8           1       2015-11-06 01:45:44.000 2015.11.06  42312   2
    Joe Blogs   1   0042f55c    8           1       2015-11-06 07:45:56.000 2015.11.06  42312   3
    Joe Blogs   1   0042f55c    8           1       2015-11-09 19:39:21.000 2015.11.09  42315   1
    Joe Blogs   1   0042f55c    8           1       2015-11-10 01:11:15.000 2015.11.10  42316   2
    Joe Blogs   1   0042f55c    8           1       2015-11-10 01:36:39.000 2015.11.10  42316   3
    Joe Blogs   1   0042f55c    8           1       2015-11-10 07:57:02.000 2015.11.10  42316   4
    Joe Blogs   1   0042f55c    8           1       2015-11-10 19:42:45.000 2015.11.10  42316   1
    Joe Blogs   1   0042f55c    8           1       2015-11-11 01:16:07.000 2015.11.11  42317   2
    Joe Blogs   1   0042f55c    8           1       2015-11-11 01:40:06.000 2015.11.11  42317   3
    Joe Blogs   1   0042f55c    8           1       2015-11-11 07:55:20.000 2015.11.11  42317   4
```

Comment: Can you edit your sample to only include the necessary details and to be more readable?  For instance the `CHINA_VISION_` prefix to the table names makes it hard to read and you have to scroll to see your query.  Since the results all have the same Name, ID, and CardCode, those details aren't really pertinent to your problem.  If you could post an example with some data on [sqlfiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/) that would be great.

Comment: Hi, The "CHINA_VISION_" prefix is needed as there are multiple tables here, and the sample data. the Name and ID are all the same, i have just edited it to remove real names, however this data all belongs to the same person, ill edit it to look more like the actual result

Comment: Do you have a table with each employee's work hours (in and out) ?

Comment: You'll get more people looking at your problem and proposing answers if your question is easier to understand.  The question you post doesn't have to compile to a query in your database and using long table names and including data not related to the actual problem will make a lot of people just skip over this question. See ["How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example"](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: Image if you had a swipe card, and each time you came in to work you had to swipe that card to say you are here, and each time you leave you swipe again. that is what CHINA_VISION_DorEvents.EventTM AS T is
So each record in T is when the employee swiped to say they are in/out,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to have some way to tell when a shift starts and ends, or is it just "the last time of a day is always the start of a shift"?  If there is a certain time, it would be easy for this case do alter the time by 5 hours to get the day number if they always clock-in after 7:00 pm:

```
FLOOR(CONVERT(FLOAT, DATEADD(hour, 5, EventTM))) AS DayNumber
```

Comment: Yeah, thanks that put's the DayNumber how i want and then i can set the InDay from this, thanks

Answer (score 0):

This is a functional question rather than a technical one... if the dates may differ, how do you know which "in" and "out" belong together? For example, the first four records MIGHT mean the emp came at 6-11 1:17, left 6-11 1:45, came 6-11 7:45, then stayed three days until 9-11 19:39.

There's only one time stamp at 9-11; how is that supposed to be processed?

You need a code for wether the emp time stamp is "in" or "out", it's the only way to determine which timespan between clock records is "present" and which is "absent".