# Query for working out worked hours

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

I have a query that get's employees clock in/out time and have grouped them as they are night shift, so the first record is the previous night

the results of this query are

```
        Name    ID          CardCode Telephone  EndOverDay          T                   Day  DayNumber InDay
        Name    Pen-005731  0042f55c    8           1       2015-11-02 19:42:12.000 2015.11.02  42309   1
        Name    Pen-005731  0042f55c    8           1       2015-11-03 01:12:08.000 2015.11.03  42309   2
        Name    Pen-005731  0042f55c    8           1       2015-11-03 01:41:43.000 2015.11.03  42309   3
        Name    Pen-005731  0042f55c    8           1       2015-11-03 07:47:25.000 2015.11.03  42309   4
        Name    Pen-005731  0042f55c    8           1       2015-11-03 19:44:02.000 2015.11.03  42310   1
        Name    Pen-005731  0042f55c    8           1       2015-11-04 01:00:01.000 2015.11.04  42310   2
        Name    Pen-005731  0042f55c    8           1       2015-11-04 01:26:30.000 2015.11.04  42310   3
        Name    Pen-005731  0042f55c    8           1       2015-11-04 07:55:55.000 2015.11.04  42310   4
        Name    Pen-005731  0042f55c    8           1       2015-11-04 19:42:51.000 2015.11.04  42311   1
        Name    Pen-005731  0042f55c    8           1       2015-11-05 01:08:35.000 2015.11.05  42311   2
        Name    Pen-005731  0042f55c    8           1       2015-11-05 01:36:20.000 2015.11.05  42311   3
        Name    Pen-005731  0042f55c    8           1       2015-11-05 07:49:14.000 2015.11.05  42311   4
        Name    Pen-005731  0042f55c    8           1       2015-11-05 19:42:37.000 2015.11.05  42312   1
        Name    Pen-005731  0042f55c    8           1       2015-11-06 01:17:05.000 2015.11.06  42312   2
        Name    Pen-005731  0042f55c    8           1       2015-11-06 01:45:44.000 2015.11.06  42312   3
        Name    Pen-005731  0042f55c    8           1       2015-11-06 07:45:56.000 2015.11.06  42312   4
        Name    Pen-005731  0042f55c    8           1       2015-11-09 19:39:21.000 2015.11.09  42316   1
        Name    Pen-005731  0042f55c    8           1       2015-11-10 01:11:15.000 2015.11.10  42316   2
        Name    Pen-005731  0042f55c    8           1       2015-11-10 01:36:39.000 2015.11.10  42316   3
        Name    Pen-005731  0042f55c    8           1       2015-11-10 07:57:02.000 2015.11.10  42316   4
        Name    Pen-005731  0042f55c    8           1       2015-11-10 19:42:45.000 2015.11.10  42317   1
        Name    Pen-005731  0042f55c    8           1       2015-11-11 01:16:07.000 2015.11.11  42317   2
        Name    Pen-005731  0042f55c    8           1       2015-11-11 01:40:06.000 2015.11.11  42317   3
        Name    Pen-005731  0042f55c    8           1       2015-11-11 07:55:20.000 2015.11.11  42317   4
```

T is the Time date of the record 
Inday is the order of swipes

I need to get the times for each DayNumber, so for daynumber 42317

it would be Datediff between the colum with Inday 1 and inday 2 and then inday 3 -4 and then added togeather get's the total time

Here is what i have so far

```
        WITH ByDays AS ( 
            SELECT     CHINA_VISION_PubPersonnel.Name, CHINA_VISION_PubPersonnel.ID, CHINA_VISION_PubCards.CardCode, CHINA_VISION_PubPersonnel.Telephone, ATDShiftDetail.EndOverDay, 
                                  CHINA_VISION_DorEvents.EventTM AS T, CONVERT(VARCHAR(10), CHINA_VISION_DorEvents.EventTM, 102) AS Day, 
                                  FLOOR(CONVERT(FLOAT, DATEADD(hour, 5, EventTM))) AS DayNumber,    
                                  ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY FLOOR(CONVERT(FLOAT,FLOOR(CONVERT(FLOAT, DATEADD(hour, 6, EventTM))))) ORDER BY FLOOR(CONVERT(FLOAT, DATEADD(hour, 5, EventTM)))) InDay  
            FROM         CHINA_VISION_PubCards INNER JOIN
                                  CHINA_VISION_PubPersonnel ON CHINA_VISION_PubCards.PubPersonnel_Ref = CHINA_VISION_PubPersonnel.Reference INNER JOIN
                                  CHINA_VISION_DorEvents ON CHINA_VISION_PubCards.CardCode = CHINA_VISION_DorEvents.CardCode INNER JOIN
                                  ATDShiftDetail ON RIGHT(CHINA_VISION_PubPersonnel.ID, 4) = ATDShiftDetail.Name
            WHERE     (CHINA_VISION_DorEvents.DorCtrls_Ref = '16') AND (CHINA_VISION_DorEvents.CardCode = '0042f55c') AND (CONVERT(Date, CHINA_VISION_DorEvents.EventTM) 
                                  > DATEADD(day,-10, GETDATE())) AND ATDShiftDetail.EndOverDay = '1'


                )
                , Diffs AS (            
                SELECT 
                    EvenRow.Day,EvenRow.DayNumber, OddRow.ID, OddRow.name , OddRow.CardCode , OddRow.Telephone ,EvenRow.EndOverDay ,
                    EvenRow.T ET, OddRow.T OT, OddRow.T-EvenRow.T Diff, 
                    DATEDIFF(S,EvenRow.T,OddRow.T) DiffSeconds -- difference in seconds
                FROM 
                    (SELECT BE.T, BE.Day, BE.InDay, BE.ID , BE.Name , Be.CardCode, BE.Telephone, BE.EndOverDay, BE.DayNumber
                     FROM ByDays BE) EvenRow -- Even rows
                INNER JOIN
                    (SELECT BO.T, BO.Day, BO.InDay , BO.ID , BO.Name , BO.CardCode, BO.Telephone, BO.EndOverDay
                     FROM ByDays BO) OddRow -- Odd rows
                ON EvenRow.InDay = OddRow.InDay +1 -- Join rows (1,2), (3,4) and so on
                   AND EvenRow.Day = OddRow.Day --  in the same day
                )


                SELECT
                    Name,
                    CardCode,
                    ID,
                    Telephone,
                    EndOverDay,
                    MIN(Day),
                    DayNumber,
                    SUM(DiffSeconds) Seconds, 
                    CONVERT(VARCHAR(8), 
                    (DATEADD(S, SUM(DiffSeconds), '1900-01-01T00:00:00')),
                    108) TotalHHMMSS -- The same, formatted as HH:MM:SS
                FROM Diffs GROUP BY DayNumber,  ID , CardCode, Name, Telephone,EndOverDay
                ORDER BY DayNumber
```

This produces a result like this.

```
        Name    CardCode          ID    Telephone   EndOverDay      Day  DayNumber  Seconds TotalHHMMSS
        Name    0042f55c    Pen-005731      8           1       2015.11.03  42309   42997   11:56:37
        Name    0042f55c    Pen-005731      8           1       2015.11.04  42310   42416   11:46:56
        Name    0042f55c    Pen-005731      8           1       2015.11.05  42311   42803   11:53:23
        Name    0042f55c    Pen-005731      8           1       2015.11.06  42312   -23331  17:31:09
        Name    0042f55c    Pen-005731      8           1       2015.11.10  42316   42343   11:45:43
        Name    0042f55c    Pen-005731      8           1       2015.11.11  42317   -23953  17:20:47
```

as you can see the correct times are not being Datdiffed, as the outcome is not correct based of the data supplied

Comment: [What have you tried?](http://mattgemmell.com/what-have-you-tried/) You said, you have a query, share it with us (with the involved tables and some sample data). Creating an [SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com) helps us too to better understand your problem. Please read [ask] in [help] and use the [site's search feature](http://stackoverflow.com/search) before asking to be sure, your question is not a duplicate.

Comment: You get this dataset and join to itself on InDay=InDay+1. That gives you the datetimes on the same line. Then you just datediff them.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Grouping multiple days together](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33646892/grouping-multiple-days-together)

Comment: Are you allowed to make changes to the table? The InDay makes no sense in its relation to clocking in/out. Be far easier to have an extra time column called clockOut then rename T to clockIn.

Comment: Unable to change the  tables , the data comes from a card swipe system

Comment: Try my query below.  I think it will get you what you are looking for.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looking for this?

```
create table punch (
    Name nvarchar(50),
    Id nvarchar(50),
    CardCode nvarchar(50),
    TelephoneEnd int,
    OverDay int,
    T datetime,
    punchDate datetime,
    DayNumber int,
    InDay int )


insert into punch 
select 'Hame',    'Pen-005731',  '0042f55c',    8,           1,   '2015-11-09 19:39:21.000', '2015.11.09',  42316,   1 union all
select 'Hame',    'Pen-005731',  '0042f55c',    8,           1,   '2015-11-10 01:11:15.000', '2015.11.10',  42316,   2 union all
select 'Hame',    'Pen-005731',  '0042f55c',    8,           1,   '2015-11-10 01:36:39.000', '2015.11.10',  42316,   3 union all
select 'Hame',    'Pen-005731',  '0042f55c',    8,           1,   '2015-11-10 07:57:02.000', '2015.11.10',  42316,   4 union all
select 'Hame',    'Pen-005731',  '0042f55c',    8,           1,   '2015-11-10 19:42:45.000', '2015.11.10',  42317,   1 union all
select 'Hame',    'Pen-005731',  '0042f55c',    8,           1,   '2015-11-11 01:16:07.000', '2015.11.11',  42317,   2 union all
select 'Hame',    'Pen-005731',  '0042f55c',    8,           1,   '2015-11-11 01:40:06.000', '2015.11.11',  42317,   3 union all
select 'Hame',    'Pen-005731',  '0042f55c',    8,           1,   '2015-11-11 07:55:20.000', '2015.11.11',  42317,   4 

select sum(x.minutesPunched)/60 as hoursWorked,
       sum(x.minutesPunched) % 60 as minutesWorked
  from (
        select datediff(mi, p2.T, p1.T) as minutesPunched
          from punch p1
          inner join punch p2 on p1.DayNumber = p2.DayNumber and p1.InDay = p2.InDay + 1
       ) x
```

Grouping with Removing 2-3 aggs:

```
select sum(x.minutesPunched)/60 as hoursWorked,
       sum(x.minutesPunched) % 60 as minutesWorked,
       x.DayNumber
  from (
        select datediff(mi, p1.T, p2.T) as minutesPunched,
               p1.DayNumber
          from punch p1
          inner join punch p2 on p1.DayNumber = p2.DayNumber and p1.InDay = p2.InDay - 1
          where (p1.InDay + 1) % 2 = 0
       ) x
 group by x.DayNumber
```

Comment: HI, thanks, i think this would work but i need a separate worked time for each day, not all days summed together, how can i do that ?

Comment: Thanks ewahner, one more thing currently this gives an out put like 12 hours minuets for example which is the total time for that day, so for example that would be from 1-4, not 1-2   3-4  as the time between 2-3 should not be counted how could i fix that?

Comment: So what you are saying is that the time between punch 2 and 3 should not be aggregated and the time between 5 and 6 and so on...I think I get it...leme give you something else

Comment: yeah exactly, imagine if you swipe a card to say your in, that's 1, then you swipe again, so your leaving, dinner for example, that 2, then 3 would be returning and then 4 would be leaving at the end of the day

Comment: Okay I updated the query...should work for you now.  I am basically removing even punchins from the left side of the join so they will only be considered on the right side of the join.  This means that an odd is a punchin...and an even is a punchout...before evens were being considered as punchins as well.